# Refresh Control UX for tvOS?

Tags: refresh, tvos

Is there an established or recommended refresh control on tvOS similar to the pull down to refresh on iOS? I noticed typical `UIKit` gesture recognizers in the tvOS SDK that I could use, for example a long press, but I was wondering whether a standardized control has emerged yet. I know from my own experience I don't think, or at least can't find, a refresh control on the YouTube app which is really frustrating.

I'm looking to refresh a `UICollectionView` in tvOS.

Comment: I don't know of any standard or widely accepted refresh gesture. What if your application updated new information automatically? Or maybe a simple `UIButton` with a refresh symbol is all that is needed.

Comment: Thanks @DanielStorm, your suggestion made me think of the tvOS life cycle, i.e. when you open a TV app, then navigate back to the home screen, then back to the app, does `ViewDidLoad` get called thus refreshing my content?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` will only get called when initially loading the view, or if you unload the view and load it again. You should look into `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidBecomeActive` , or  `UIViewController`'s `viewDidAppear`. There's a few different ways to go about this. Which one you use depends on your applications flow.

Comment: Good points, thanks Daniel

Comment: Another idea might be tracking a double circle motion on the Siri Remote touch pad. That might be interesting.

Comment: Custom you mean?  That's not an existing gesture is it? Personally as a user my intuition is to either force touch like on the watch, or pull down to refresh.

Comment: Yeah you'd have to create it yourself. It does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

There are NO any refresh control element in tvOS. However you can use:

- A `UIButton` with refresh action.
- `viewDidAppear`, viewWillAppear
- `applicationWillEnterForeground`